# R: cumulative sum resetting every n rows

Tags: r, cumulative-sum, cumsum

##### Reprex

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(week = rep(rep(c(1,2), each=5), times=98),
                 day = rep(c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"), times = 98),
                 hours = round(runif(490, min=0,max=10)))
```

```
head(df, n=12L)
   week       day hours
1     1    Monday     6
2     1   Tuesday     0
3     1 Wednesday     3
4     1  Thursday     3
5     1    Friday     8
6     2    Monday     3
7     2   Tuesday     7
8     2 Wednesday     9
9     2  Thursday     9
10    2    Friday     1
11    1    Monday     8
12    1   Tuesday     3
```

---

##### Problem

Been struggling for some time now to create a cumulative sum of variable `hours` above that resets every new `week`, using R Studio. The only solutions I've [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994060/r-cumulative-sum-by-condition-with-reset?noredirect=1&lq=1) involve [reset conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076769/dplyr-r-cumulative-sum-with-reset) that fall short in my case, as random daily fluctuations in variable `hours` cause any threshold I set to be reached earlier or later than intended, in at least some weeks. For example:

```
sum_reset_at <- function(thresh) {
  function(x) {
    accumulate(x, ~if_else(.x==thresh, .y, .x+.y))
  }
}

df %>% mutate(test = sum_reset_at(20)(hours)) %>% head(n=15L)
   week       day hours test
1     1    Monday     6    6
2     1   Tuesday     0    6
3     1 Wednesday     3    9
4     1  Thursday     3   12
5     1    Friday     8   20
6     2    Monday     3    3
7     2   Tuesday     7   10
8     2 Wednesday     9   19
9     2  Thursday     9   28
10    2    Friday     1    1
11    1    Monday     8    9
12    1   Tuesday     3   12
13    1 Wednesday     1   13
14    1  Thursday    10   23
15    1    Friday     4    4
```

Instead, is it possible to reset the cumulative sum at every instance of "Monday" in variable `day`, or every 'n' times? Or would it make sense to create a new iterative `week_itera` variable (i.e. increases to '3', then '4', rather than cycling back to '1' and '2', etc.), then adapt [the solution posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925600/r-cumulative-sum-by-condition?rq=1) to add together `hours` for each week?

Comment: If it should be on every 'Monday', do a grouping i.e. `df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(day == "Monday")) %>% mutate(test = sum_reset_at(20)(hours)) %>% head(15)` or if it `n` rows, `n <- 10; df %>% group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), n, n()))) %>% mutate(test = sum_reset_at(20)(hours))`

Answer (score 0):

The first version resets every 5 rows, the second resets every Monday:

```
df$test1 <- ave(df$hours, (seq_along(df$hours)-1)%/%5 , FUN=cumsum )
```

or

```
df$test2 <- ave(df$hours, cumsum(df$day=="Monday") , FUN=cumsum )


> df
    week       day hours test1 test2
1      1    Monday     6     6     6
2      1   Tuesday     0     6     6
3      1 Wednesday     3     9     9
4      1  Thursday     3    12    12
5      1    Friday     8    20    20
6      2    Monday     3     3     3
7      2   Tuesday     7    10    10
8      2 Wednesday     9    19    19
9      2  Thursday     9    28    28
10     2    Friday     1    29    29
11     1    Monday     8     8     8
12     1   Tuesday     3    11    11
13     1 Wednesday     1    12    12
14     1  Thursday    10    22    22
15     1    Friday     4    26    26
```